# how to deal with data.table column as.character in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data.table rather data.frame(for a faster code). Despite the syntax difference between than, I'm having problems when I need to extract a specific character column and use it as character vector. When I call:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("file.txt")
vect <- as.character(DT[, 1, with = FALSE])
class(vect)
###[1] "character"
head(vect)
```

It returns:

```
[1] "c(\"uc003hzj.4\", \"uc021ofx.1\", \"uc021olu.1\", \"uc021ome.1\", \"uc021oov.1\", \"uc021opl.1\", \"uc021osl.1\", \"uc021ovd.1\", \"uc021ovp.1\", \"uc021pdq.1\", \"uc021pdv.1\", \"uc021pdw.1\")
```

Any ideas of how to avoid these "\" in the output?

Comment: You say it's already a character column, so `v = DT[, colname]` - that's it; other alternatives are `DT[["colname"]]` or `DT[[colidx]]`

Comment: I get it! Thank you sir! Good alternatives!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as.character` works on `vector`s and not on `data.frame/data.table` objects in the way the OP expected.  So, if we need to get the first column as `character` class, subset with `.SD[[1L]]` and apply the `as.character`

```
DT[, as.character(.SD[[1L]])]
```

If there are multiple columns, we can specify the column index with `.SDcols` and loop over the `.SD` to convert to `character` and assign (`:=`) the output back to the particular columns.

```
DT[, (1:2) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols= 1:2]
```

#### data

```
DT <- data.table(Col1 = 1:5, Col2= 6:10, Col3= LETTERS[1:5])
```

Comment: Yep! That was fast!  This fix my problem, without any need to call the col name, but only the col number! Thank you very much!!